# Making the database password protected in Android OS Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I am using Sql cipher for making the database password protected, but it's not working on Ice Cream Sandwich, Is Sql cipher is available for android 4.0.3 and if not is there any other way of doing that.

Please help.

N.B. The way should be open source.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLCipher for Android](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher) supports Android 2.1 - 4.0.3.  Support for ICS was added in our 1.1 release, however our current version of the library is 2.0.8 which you can get [here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/downloads).

Comment: so from where will i get the support for ICS.